# Android Espresso - Running instrumentation tests on a different app version

Tags: android, android-studio, automated-tests, android-espresso

Our team has a lot of new instrumentation tests on the develop branch but there are only a few tests on the older release branches.

What is the best way you guys could think of to run those newer tests on the older app versions whose branches don't have those tests?

My only idea here is to cherry-pick those instrumentation test commits but it sounds too painful and gruesome.

The best scenario I could think of (but don't really know how to do) is to have an older develop build of the app and somehow run those new tests there, but is that even possible?